# FastLED and Adafruit Gemma M0 - Getting started

Tags: led, adafruit

I just bought a Gemma M0 and I'm trying to use it with FastLED. There are several forums that discuss the same errors I get when I try to upload my code, but they all involve editing .h files, something I'm not comfortable doing without understanding the reason behind the change. Is there a place where I can get a basic starting point for using FastLED with the Gemma M0?

I tried the Quick Example in the FastLED Overview:

```
#include "FastLED.h" CRGB leds[1];

void setup() { 
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, 6>(leds, 1); }

void loop() { 
  leds[0] = CRGB::White; FastLED.show(); delay(30); 
  leds[0] = CRGB::Black; FastLED.show(); delay(30); }
```

and I get these errors:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Mac OS X), Board: "Adafruit Gemma M0, Small (-Os) (standard), Arduino, Off"
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
In file included from /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/blink/blink.ino:1:
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/FastLED.h:14:21: note: #pragma message: FastLED version 3.004.000
   14 | #    pragma message "FastLED version 3.004.000"
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/FastLED.h:65,
                 from /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/blink/blink.ino:1:
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/fastspi.h:135:23: note: #pragma message: No hardware SPI pins defined.  All SPI access will default to bitbanged output
  135 | #      pragma message "No hardware SPI pins defined.  All SPI access will default to bitbanged output"
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/FastLED.h:48,
                 from /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/blink/blink.ino:1:
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/fastpin.h: In instantiation of 'class FastPin<6>':
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/fastpin.h:242:29:   required from 'class FastPinBB<6>'
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/platforms/arm/d21/clockless_arm_d21.h:10:54:   required from 'class ClocklessController<6, 12, 30, 18, GRB, 0, false, 50>'
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/chipsets.h:578:7:   required from 'class WS2812Controller800Khz<6, GRB>'
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/FastLED.h:92:34:   required from 'class NEOPIXEL<6>'
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/FastLED.h:314:28:   required from 'static CLEDController& CFastLED::addLeds(CRGB*, int, int) [with CHIPSET = NEOPIXEL; unsigned char DATA_PIN = 6]'
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/blink/blink.ino:4:60:   required from here
/Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/src/fastpin.h:210:24: error: static assertion failed: Invalid pin specified
  210 |  static_assert(validpin(), "Invalid pin specified");
      |                ~~~~~~~~^~
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Adafruit Gemma M0.
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `starting point`... example code in the arduino IDE

Comment: The Arduino IDE Examples don’t cover the difference between types of hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemma does not have a pin 6. `FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, 6>(leds, 1);` I changed to pin 2 and it works. `FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, 2>(leds, 1);`